# WKWebView dynamic height calculation based on font size

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, wkwebview, javascript-injection

I'm trying to calculate WKWebView content height according to font size. There is a lot of topic about it but none of it worked for me. I created demo app for test. In my test app I'm changing size of font via slider and I tried to calculate size of cell but I didn't get correct content size of webView.

Simply app work like that

1. Text downloaded from web.
2. Splitted to html array for add a different cell between webviews
   cell.
3. When split html I add some tag for javascript injection(like
   font size and font color)
4. Slider inject new font size to webviews and after that calculate
   webView height again.

https://github.com/gelasdev/gelasdev-wkWebviewResize